# Jumpy, Jerky, Erratic mouse in VMWare Mavericks

Tags: linux, mouse, vmware

after installing maverick on my vmware, host linux, the mouse was erratic, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are an accumulative solutions that I tried and I think updating of the VMWARE tools is what worked for me.

Possible Solutions:
1. go to the main window > edit > preferences > input, change the option optimize mouse for games, to either ALWAYS or NEVER

2. update the vmware tools
3. adding the USB controller and selecting > all USB input device
4. add the following to the vmx file by right clicking on it and opening it up in a text editor

   **mouse.vusb.enable = "TRUE"
   mouse.vusb.useBasicMouse = "FALSE"**

My solution was a combo of 3 and 4 it took me a day to figure this out so I really hope it helps.